# How to display and edit an RTF?

Tags: .net, winforms, rtf

What is the best way in `.NET` to populate an `RTF` form and then display it and make it editable by the user?

Answer (score 0):

You can use a richtext box.

To load it with rtf:

```
richtextbox1.RTF = @"{\rtf...}";
```

A richtextbox is editable, as long as you don't change its default settings.